# For loop for Array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, for-loop

I have sample code as below:

```
$IP=@("IP1","IP2","IP3", "IP4" , "IP5")
$Hostname=@("Host1","Host2","Host3","HOST4", "HOST5")

$data = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the data.'

if ($data -match 'zone1') {
    $Unity=$IP[0]
    $show=$hostname[0]
} elseif ($data -match 'site2'){
    $Unity=$IP[1]
    $show=$hostname[1]
} elseif ($data -match 'unit5'){
    $Unity=$IP[2]
    $show=$hostname[2]
} elseif ($data -match 'ALL DC'){
    $Unity=$IP
    $show=$hostname
}



foreach ($u in $Unity){

  echo "This is my IP" $u
  echo "This is my hostname" $show

}
```

Codework fine for all the options except ALL DC.
I want to run some command which uses hostname and Ip.

Desired Output when ALL DC is input by the user is

> This is my IP
> IP1
> This is my hostname
> Host1
> This is my IP
> IP2
> This is my hostname
> Host2
> This is my IP
> IP3
> This is my hostname
> Host3
> This is my IP
> IP4
> This is my hostname
> Host4
> This is my IP
> IP5
> This is my hostname
> Host5

Comment: Is this the actual code? You access `$data` before assigning it.

Comment: @marsze-This is the sample code and I have corrected it

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve. Please explain your intention better, and include expected input/output

Comment: @marsze if you ll run above code and will enter input as ALL DC, you ll come to know about my issue. For one IP it’s showing all hostname

Comment: Yes, because you assign all hostnames `$show = $hostname`. What exactly do you want the output to be? Add that to your question!

Comment: @marsze-Question updated with the desired output for ALL DC option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the number of assignments required by using a `switch` instead of `if`/`elseif`/`else`, and then only picking the array indices (instead of the target items):

```
$indices = switch -regex ($data){
    'zone1' { 0 }
    'site2' { 1 } 
    'unit5' { 2 }
    'ALL DC' { 0..4 }
}

$Unity=$IP[$indices]
$show=$hostname[$indices]
```

Now you just need to replace the `foreach` loop with a `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $Indices.Length; $i++){
  $u = $Unity[$i]
  $h = $show[$i]

  echo "This is my IP" $u
  echo "This is my hostname" $h
}
```

---

Alternatively, construct objects based on the original arrays before letting the user choose:

```
$IP=@("IP1","IP2","IP3", "IP4" , "IP5")
$Hostname=@("Host1","Host2","Host3","HOST4", "HOST5")

# construct a new array of objects with corresponding IP-Host details
$HostIPDetails = for($i = 0; $i -lt $IP.Length; $i++){
  [pscustomobject]@{ IP = $IP[$i]; HostName = $Hostname[$i] }
}

$data = Read-Host 'Input the data... '

$indices = switch -regex ($data){
    'zone1' { 0 }
    'site2' { 1 } 
    'unit5' { 2 }
    'ALL DC' { 0..4 }
}

foreach($machine in $HostIPDetails[$indices]){
  echo "This is my IP" $machine.IP
  echo "This is my hostname" $machine.HostName 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much Theo and Mathias for your help and effort.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, I would probably not use separate arrays for this, but one single array containing **objects** in order to keep the units, ip's and hostnames together.

Then you could do:

```
$units = [PsCustomObject]@{unit = 'zone1'  ; ip = 'IP1'; hostname = 'Host1'},
         [PsCustomObject]@{unit = 'site2'  ; ip = 'IP2'; hostname = 'Host2'},
         [PsCustomObject]@{unit = 'unit5'  ; ip = 'IP3'; hostname = 'Host3'},
         [PsCustomObject]@{unit = 'region3'; ip = 'IP4'; hostname = 'Host4'},
         [PsCustomObject]@{unit = 'zone5'  ; ip = 'IP5'; hostname = 'Host5'}

$data = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the unit'

$choice = if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($data)) { $units | Where-Object { $_.unit -match $data }}
if ($choice) {
    Write-Host "You have chosen:" -ForegroundColor Green
    $choice | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
else {
    Write-Host "You have given invalid input.." -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host "These are all DC's:"
    $units | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

Is that your intent? If not, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64412160/edit) your question to make it more clear.

Comment: your code is fine but in this, I have to mention a huge set of commands which are using variable IP and hostname twice under if and else statement which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @GURUSINGH There is no mention of that in the question.. However, I don't see the problem. In the `if {}` you do something using `$choice.ip` and `$choice.hostname` while in the `else{}` you do something different, looping over all items in the `$units` array.